# Target (session and entity java files) unreachable in JBoss Seam

Tags: java, jboss, jakarta-ee, seam

I am new to JBoss Seam. I wanted to test some stuff on Eclipse so I created a new project and attached it to a mysql db. I then created a seam entity that I wanted to use to connect to my db. This seam entity created a .xhtml file and then a .java file. The problem am having now is that when I run the file to see whether I can persist in the db, I get the following error

```
Exception during request processing:
Caused by javax.servlet.ServletException with message: "/person.xhtml @21,67 value="#{personHome.instance.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'personHome' resolved to null"
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:277)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException with message: "/person.xhtml @21,67 value="#{personHome.instance.name}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'personHome' resolved to null"
com.sun.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:62)
com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:92)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:942)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:868)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1072)
javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:672)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1058)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1058)
javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1058)
javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:235)
org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot$3.invokeContextCallback(AjaxViewRoot.java:439)
org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:238)
org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processValidators(AjaxViewRoot.java:455)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:178)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:368)
org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:495)
org.jboss.seam.web.Ajax4jsfFilter.doFilter(Ajax4jsfFilter.java:56)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Please what could the problem be because I cannot see what am not doing well. Also when starting the server (JBoss), I got this warning

```
[PersistentPermissionResolver] no permission store available - please install a PermissionStore with the name 'org.jboss.seam.security.jpaPermissionStore' if persistent permissions are required.
```

What is the cause of this warning and how can I eliminate it?

Thanks

Person.xhtml and Person.java files

```
<h:form id="personForm">

    <rich:panel>
        <f:facet name="header">person</f:facet>

        <s:decorate id="nameField" template="layout/edit.xhtml">
            <ui:define name="label">Name</ui:define>
            <h:inputText id="name" required="true"
                         value="#{personHome.instance.name}"/>
        </s:decorate>

        <div style="clear:both"/>

    </rich:panel>

    <div class="actionButtons">
        <h:commandButton id="save"
                      value="Save"
                     action="#{personHome.persist}"
                   rendered="#{!personHome.managed}"/>
        <h:commandButton id="update"
                      value="Save"
                     action="#{personHome.update}"
                   rendered="#{personHome.managed}"/>
        <h:commandButton id="delete"
                      value="Delete"
                     action="#{personHome.remove}"
                  immediate="true"
                   rendered="#{personHome.managed}"/>
        <s:button propagation="end"
                           id="cancel"
                        value="Cancel"
                         view="/personList.xhtml"/>
    </div>

</h:form>
```

and the java file

```
package org.domain.work.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Version;
import org.hibernate.validator.Length;

@Entity
public class person implements Serializable
{
    // seam-gen attributes (you should probably edit these)
    private Long id;
    private Integer version;
    private String name;

    // add additional entity attributes

    // seam-gen attribute getters/setters with annotations (you probably should edit)

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Version
    public Integer getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    private void setVersion(Integer version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Length(max = 20)
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

personHome.java

```
package org.domain.work.session;

import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Name;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.Begin;
import org.jboss.seam.annotations.web.RequestParameter;
import org.jboss.seam.framework.EntityHome;

import org.domain.work.entity.person;

@Name("personHome")
public class personHome extends EntityHome
{
    @RequestParameter Long personId;

    @Override
    public Object getId()
    {
        if (personId == null)
        {
            return super.getId();
        }
        else
        {
            return personId;
        }
    }

    @Override @Begin
    public void create() {
        super.create();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the file `person.xhtml` you use Seam component `personHome`, but these component is not define.

You can try find class `PersonHome` and add such adnotation:

```
@Name("personHome")
public class PersonHome {
```

Mayby some reference can help you:

1. [Registration example](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/tutorial.html#registration-example) - simple Seam application
2. [Home objects](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/framework.html#d0e8237) - explanation of Home object

---

In your source file you have a few things that don't follow Java convetion and at least one error:

1. The `personHome` component should be declare in that way:

   ```
   @Name("personHome")
   public class PersonHome extends EntityHome<Person>
   ```

   You should add extend  `EntityHome` class with your entity and use capital letter when you declare class name.
2. You should also use capital letter when you declare `Person` class:

   ```
   @Entity
   public class Person implements Serializable
   ```
3. Problem with data source: plese check if you declare data source `workDatasource` and if proper file exist in your `deploy` directory. File with data source definition should have name which end `-ds.xml`. You can also past that file in your query.

Comment: I have and I always had a personHome class that has that annotation. That is why I am wondering why I have the same problem. Is there any other thing that can be the cause?

Comment: Sorry, it is hard to say something more. Mayby you have some extra info? How you create the project? If it works befeore some changes?

Comment: I created the project using Eclipse i.e. new Seam Web Project. I set the project to use mysql db. I can view the (xhtml) pages that I creattd but I have not been able to perform any kind of interaction with my database.

Could it be the permission store thing?

Comment: Permission store is connected with permission and as I remember you can ignore these error unless you use security base on Drools.

Mayby you can pase some context: relevant fragments from Java file and XHTML page.

Comment: How do you use `personHome`? Do you inject it somwhere (using `@In`)?

Comment: Could you put it in your query? Its quite unreadable in the comments.

Comment: I have added the files. I also noticed that am getting this deployment error

 Deployment "jboss.jca:name=workDatasource,service=DataSourceBinding" is in error due to the following reason(s): ** NOT FOUND Depends on 'jboss.jca:name=workDatasource,service=DataSourceBinding' **

Pls what does this mean?

Comment: It means it cannot find your datasource file - this is an xml file. I tend to put these into the JBoss deploy directory, to allow the EARs to access it, although this may not be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Is your personHome class defined in the same project as the JSF pages?

I had a similar problem recently, based around my move to Maven. It turned out that the JBoss Seam jar was in the EAR lib directory and in the WAR web-inf/lib directory, and this caused a conflict.

Comment: Of course not. When a seam project is created, 3 or 4 projects could be created i.e. projectname, projectname-ear, projectname-ejb and projectname-test. My personHome class is inside the projectname-ejb folder and the (nb: am not using jsf) xhtml pages are in the projectname folder

Comment: And does your EAR contain the EJB project, with the correct references in the application.xml?

Comment: Am using JBoss Seam Tools for Eclipse so all that is taken care of automatically